# How can I add a row in a table from a Linux Shell?

Tags: table, linux

I'm looking to do some scripting here so I can easily just have an application or script automatically add a row for me without needing me to use the UI and do it manually.

Is this possible?

Comment: What's Tablepress?

Comment: @bravokeyl https://tablepress.org -- It is a plugin centred around tables.

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume you can use [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) for that.

Especially [`wp db import`](https://wp-cli.org/commands/db/import/) should be usable for that.

Last but not least the [MySQL Command-Line Tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html) itself, which I'd think is used by WP-CLI for the tasks, can be used.

A word of warning though, there might be some logic to consider regarding the rows you want to add to the table. That logic might not be easily reproducible - or you have to rebuild it - when doing things from the CLI.

So it might be better to use the according and existing functions for the import or adding of rows, because those have the logic implemented already. You can go that route by working with a custom PHP script, the loading of `wp-load.php` will be necessary - at least. This approach is pretty good documented, so just search this site and the net for it.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it right away, and let you know if I get any code working.